# How to read each file data in node side while uploading multiple files from multer via AJAX?

Tags: node.js, ajax, upload, multer

Below I have selected 3 files. On submit the the files get uploaded successfully to the destination. But also I want to read all the 3 files attributes like filename, path etc. on server side means
in nodejs. How to do that?
[image]

I am trying to fnd it in req.body and req.query by printing it in console but i am getting all as one object : [object Object]

Below is my node side code:

```
 router.post('/api/upload/:cid',function(req,res){
      // console.log("REQ",req); //file is there in the body
      console.log("yes it came under api");
      console.log("req.body = "+ req.body);
      console.log("req.query = "+ req.query);
      console.log("req.data = "+ req.data);

  upload2(req,res,function(err) {
      if(err) {
          return res.end("Error uploading file.");
      }
      else
      {
      console.log("File is uploaded");
      res.redirect('/taskswriter');

  }
});
})
```

Here is the AJAX code:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(r){
            console.log("result",r)
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("some error", e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using multer on server side, to get files data (filename, path etc.) you need to get it from:

```js
// If you are uploading multiples files
console.log(request.files);

// If you are uploading one file
console.log(request.file);
```

So, probably you will be able to get it with:

```js
router.post('/api/upload/:cid',function(req,res){
   console.log("req.files", req.files);
```